# Is it possible to display array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to make some batleships, but I don't know if it is posible to display a 2D array for the playing ground?

Comment: Yes; it is possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: There is no `printf` format for displaying arrays (other than the special case of `"%s"` for character strings), if that's what you meant. The way to display an array is to loop over the elements and display each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char arr[SIZE][SIZE];

int i,j;

for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

   for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

      arr[i][j] = 'O'; //initalizes

      printf(" %c ",arr[i][j]); //prints

   }
   purchar('\n'); //to break every row

}
```

update spot to X when it has been hit, and print again w/o the initializer line

sorry the code came out weird, but it's basically a nested for loop, each counting to predefined size of game board, can be indexed from 0,SIZE-1
maybe make it a char array and use O and X and then other characters to draw the ships put out, honestly i'd make the ships eight, equals equals and a capital D, but the choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a [for loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#C). They usually took something like this:

```
size_t i; // size_t is an unsigned int large enough to hold a string's length
for(i = 0; i < size_of_my_array; ++i) {
    // do stuff with my_array[i]
}
```

For example, to print the characters in a string individually (not necessarily the most efficient way):

```
char* name = "Brendan";
size_t i; // size_t is an unsigned int large enough to hold a string's length
for(i = 0; i < strlen(name); ++i) {
    printf("%c", name[i]);
}
```

Looping over other kinds of arrays is similar.